# How to reduce the height of keyboard using custom renderer in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, keyboard

I want to customize my Keyboard using custom renderer in Xamarin forms. I want to reduce the height of keyboard and add a tab key if possible. I don't know what function will help me to do that. This is my custom renderer code.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.InputScope = Element.Keyboard.ToInputScope();
                InputScope inputScope = new InputScope();
                inputScope.Names.Add(new InputScopeName
                {
                    NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.NumericPin // For 0-9 only
                                                               //NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.Number // for numerics, but allowing other characters
                                                               //NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.CurrencyAmountAndSymbol // For monetary values
                });


            }
        }
```

I want this to be done only for UWP. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can show the effect picture you need, this will be helpful. In general, the system keyboard size cannot be modified unless it is a custom keyboard.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT can u give me an example for custom keyboard?

Comment: Sorry, I found UWP can not custom keyboard like ios or android.However , If you reduce the keyboard height just to not obscure other controls, then there are other solutions. For example, when the keyboard pops up, you can change the height of the occluded control.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/respond-to-the-presence-of-the-touch-keyboard And you can add a tab key when keyboard showing, remove tab key when keyboard hiding.